# Php calculation is posting as 0

Tags: php, calculated-field

I am having a problem with getting the calculation to post anything but 0. all other post has the correct info from the form but the calculation is not working. all the data that comes from the inputs and the calculation of the total pallets works. It is just the total price.

The whole form:

```
if(!checkAdmin()) {
header("Location: login.php");
exit();
}

$page_limit = 10; 




// filter GET values
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
$get[$key] = filter($value);
}

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
$post[$key] = filter($value);
}


$rs_all = mysql_query("select count(*) as total_all from users") or     die(mysql_error());


list($all) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_all);
?>
<?php
$rs_pickup = mysql_query("select count(*) as total_all from pickups") or     die(mysql_error());
list($pickup) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_pickup);
?>
<?php
$sql="SELECT companyid, company FROM company "; 
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

$options=""; 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$id=$row["companyid"]; 
$thing=$row["company"]; 
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing.'</option>'; 
} 
?>
<?php

?>
<?php 
$err = array();

if($_POST['doPickup'] == 'Enter Pickup') 
if(empty($err)) {


$companyid = $_POST['companyid'];

$sql_grd = "SELECT companyid, grade_a_pu, grade_b_pu, grade_c_pu, ns_pu, custom_pu FROM company WHERE companyid = $companyid";
$result_grd=mysql_query($sql_grd) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row_grd=mysql_fetch_array($result_grd)) 
{

$price_a = $row_grd["grade_a_pu"];
$price_b = $row_grd["grade_b_pu"];
$price_c = $row_grd["grade_c_pu"];
$price_ns = $row_grd["ns_pu"];
$price_cus = $row_grd["custom_pu"];

}
$total_credit = (($_POST['grade_a_pal']*$price_a)+($_POST['grade_b_pal']*$price_b)+($_POST['grade_c_pal']*$price_c)+($_POST['ns_pal']*$price_ns)+($_POST['cus_pal']*$price_cus));

$sql_insert = "INSERT into `pickups`
         (`companyid`,`pu_date`,`trail_num`,`grade_a_pal`,`grade_b_pal`,`grade_c_pal`,`ns_pal`,`cus_pal`,`pal_pu`,`credit`)
        VALUES          ('$_POST[companyid]','$_POST[pu_date]','$_POST[trail_num]','$_POST[grade_a_pal]','$_POST[grade_b_pal]','$_POST[grade_c_pal]','$_POST[ns_pal]','$_POST[cus_pal]','$_POST[pal_pu]','$total_credit')";

mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());

}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>USMI Pallets, Inc. :: Pickup Entry Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
  });
 });
  </script>
 </head>

  <body>
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <?php include("header.php"); ?>
 <tr>
<td colspan="3" height="23" valign="top" style="background-color:#A42914 ">
</td>
</tr>

<?php include("admin_menu.php"); ?>

<td width="800" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;">
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="myaccount">
    <tr>
      <td>Total Pickups: <?php echo $pickup;?></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <p><?php 
  if(!empty($msg)) {
  echo $msg[0];
  }
  ?></p>

    <table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #E4F8FA;padding: 2px 5px;border: 1px solid #CAE4FF;" >
    <tr>
      <td><form name="form1" method="get" action="pickup_ent.php">
           <p align="center">Search Account: 
           <SELECT NAME=companyid id="q"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>Choose
        <?=$options?>
        </SELECT> 
            <br>
            </p>




          <p align="center"> 
            <input name="doSearch" type="submit" id="doSearch2" value="Search">
          </p>
          </form></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
   <?php if ($get['doSearch'] == 'Search') {


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM pickups WHERE companyid = '$_REQUEST[companyid]' ORDER BY pu_date DESC";


  $rs_total = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  $total = mysql_num_rows($rs_total);

  if (!isset($_GET['page']) )
    { $start=0; } else
    { $start = ($_GET['page'] - 1) * $page_limit; }

  $rs_results = mysql_query($sql . " limit $start,$page_limit") or die(mysql_error());
  $total_pages = ceil($total/$page_limit);

  ?>
 <?php 

  // outputting the pages
    if ($total > $page_limit)
    {
    echo "<div><strong>Pages:</strong> ";
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $page_limit)
    {


    $page_no = $i+1;
    $qstr = ereg_replace("&page=[0-9]+","",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    echo "<a href=\"pickup_ent.php?$qstr&page=$page_no\">$page_no</a> ";
    $i++;
    }
    echo "</div>";
    }  ?>   
 <form name "searchform" action="pickup_ent.php" method="post">          
 <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
     <tr bgcolor="#E6F3F9"> 
<td class="myheader">ID</td>
<td class="myheader">Company #</td>
<td class="myheader">Date</td>
<td class="myheader">Trailer Number</td>
<td class="myheader">Grade A</td>
<td class="myheader">Grade B</td>
<td class="myheader">Grade C</td>
<td class="myheader">Non-Std</td>
<td class="myheader">Custom</td>
<td class="myheader">Total Pickup</td>
<td class="myheader">Total Credit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
 <?php while ($rrows = mysql_fetch_array($rs_results)) {?>
 <tr> 
        <td> <div align="center"><?php echo $rrows['pickup_id']; ?></div>   </td>
        <td> <div align="center"><?php echo $rrows['companyid']; ?></div></td>
        <td> <div align="center"><?php echo $rrows['pu_date']; ?></div></td>
        <td> <div align="center"><?php echo $rrows['trail_num'];?></div></td>
        <td> <div align="center"><?php echo $rrows['grade_a_pal'];?></div></td>
        <td> <div align="center"><?php echo $rrows['grade_b_pal'];?></div></td>
        <td> <div align="center"><?php echo $rrows['grade_c_pal'];?></div></td>
        <td> <div align="center"><?php echo $rrows['ns_pal'];?></div></td>
        <td> <div align="center"><?php echo $rrows['cus_pal'];?></div></td>
        <td> <div align="center"><?php echo $rrows['pal_pu'];?></div></td>
        <td> <div align="center">$<?php echo $rrows['credit'];?></div></td>
        <td width="10%"><a href="edit_pu.php?pickup_id=<?php echo $rrows['pickup_id']; ?>">Edit</a>&nbsp;<a href="delete_pu.php?pickup_id=<?php echo $rrows['pickup_id']; ?>">Delete</a></td> 
                  </tr>
      <tr> 

      <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <p><br>


  </form>
  <?php } ?>

  &nbsp;</p>    

<h2><font color="#FF0000">Pickup Entry 
    Page</font></h2>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <form name "pickupform" action="pickup_ent.php" method="post">
  <table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #E4F8FA;padding: 2px 5px;border: 1px solid #CAE4FF;" >
    <tr>
      <td>
      Account: 
        <SELECT NAME=companyid> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>Choose 
        <?=$options?> 
        </SELECT> </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
       <td>Date: <input name="pu_date" type="text" id="datepicker" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Trailer #:<select name="trail_num" id="trail_num">
                    <option selected value=""></option>
                    <option value="1986-1">1986-1</option>
                    <option value="1986-2">1986-2</option>
                    <option value="1986-3">1986-3</option>
                    <option value="1986-4">1986-4</option>
                    <option value="1986-5">1986-5</option>
                    <option value="1986-6">1986-6</option>
                    <option value="1986-7">1986-7</option>
                    <option value="1986-8">1986-8</option>
                    <option value="1986-9">1986-9</option>
                    <option value="1986-10">1986-10</option>
                    <option value="1986-11">1986-10</option>
                    <option value="1986-12">1986-12</option>
                    </select></td>
    </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>Grade A Pallets: <input id="grade_a_pal" name="grade_a_pal" type="text" size="8"> </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Grade B Pallets: <input id="grade_b_pal" name="grade_b_pal" type="text" size="8"> </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Grade C Pallets: <input id="grade_c_pal" name="grade_c_pal" type="text" size="8"> </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Non-Standard Pallets: <input id="ns_pal" name="ns_pal" type="text" size="8"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Custom Pallets: <input id="cus_pal" name="cus_pal" type="text" size="8"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Total Pallets Picked Up:
         <input id="pal_pu" name="pal_pu" type="text" size="8" readonly></td>
       </tr>

       <td><input name="doPickup" type="submit" id="doPickup" value="Enter Pickup"></p>
        </td>
     </tr>

  </table>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 //this calculates values automatically
 sum();
 $("#grade_a_pal, #grade_b_pal, #grade_c_pal, #cus_pal").on("keydown keyup",   function() {
sum();
 });
});

function sum() {
 var grade_a_pal = document.getElementById('grade_a_pal').value;
 var grade_b_pal = document.getElementById('grade_b_pal').value;
 var grade_c_pal = document.getElementById('grade_c_pal').value;
 var ns_pal = document.getElementById('ns_pal').value;
 var cus_pal = document.getElementById('cus_pal').value;
 var result = parseInt(grade_a_pal) + parseInt(grade_b_pal) +  parseInt(grade_c_pal) + parseInt(ns_pal) + parseInt(cus_pal);
 if (!isNaN(result)) {
 document.getElementById('pal_pu').value = result;
 }
 }
</script>
  </form>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p></td>
<td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="43" valign="top" style="background-color:#A42914 ">
<table width="766" style="height:100% " border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="myfooter">
<div style="margin:12px 0px 0px 31px; ">

&copy; 2012 USMI Pallets, Inc. All rights reserved
</div>

    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `$total_credit` the line that's not working as you'd like? If so, you might want to `// flag that line with a comment`.

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injection doing this. Start using PDO now before the mysql library gets removed with PHP 7

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using $_post (lower case) instead of $_POST (uppercase) for your pallets vars.

Try outputting a print_r($_POST) to see what you are getting in your $_POST array.  It could just be you are referencing the wrong vars.

Comment: Changed the $_post to $_POST still did not work. can seem to add the print_r($_POST) to the right spot to get that to work.

Comment: Can you show the form or add a fiddle so we can see everything?